# How can I see the same messages in WhatsApp on my phone as well as the browser when WhatsApp uses end-to-end encryption?

Tags: security, whatsapp

When I open WhatsApp on both my mobile phone and web browser, I see same messages on both clients. But because WhatsApp uses end-to-end encryption, I should not be able to see messages sent from mobile on the web client, because it should use different pair of private/public keys.

So how it is possible that the communication shows in web? Does it have same keys?

I don’t think so…

My theory is that the only encrypted communication is to mobile phone, and then mobile phone sends messages over different link to web browser. That different link may not have strong assymetric encryption and can be a weakness. What do you think?

Comment: The encryption on WhatsApp is account-based “end-to-end” encryption; it is not a per-device form of encryption. Meaning wherever you are logged in, your keys are used to manage your access to your account and messages. If your theory of how it works were true then — for example — if you most your phone, then how could you ever login to WhatsApp again? Read more on [their official FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/28030015/): “WhatsApp end-to-end encryption ensures only you and the person you're communicating with can read what's sent, and nobody in between, not even WhatsApp.”

Comment: That is actually correct. If you lost your phone and you are not logged in, then you can not login in web client. Therefore I think that web client communicates rather with phone than with Whatsapp servers...

Comment: And in that case losing your phone would mean two-factor authentication would not work. But unless your phone number changes, you can then get a new phone and login to WhatsApp again and then authorize a two-factor login on you web client. You are overthinking this and misunderstanding what two-factor authentication is versus what end-to-end encryption is.

Comment: OK this is how I understand your sentence "Meaning wherever you are logged in, your keys are used to manage your access to your account and messages" as: when you log in in web client, it must have keys to access the account. But where does it get the keys from?

Comment: Maybe I miswrote that, but perhaps WhatsApp creates new keys on your device and then associates them with your account. But at the end of the day this is all *account-based encryption*. Your account is the authority, not the device.

Comment: I understand that Telegram developers can not enable end to end encryption by default, because it would not be able to access same messages on different devices - because each device encrypts messages with its own key. So I think that Whatsapp somehow bypasses this and in the chain server-mobile-web something is not end to end encrypted. But Whatsap's code is not public, it is proprietary, so we will never know for sure.

Comment: “But Whatsap's code is not public, it is proprietary, so we will never know for sure.” Exactly why despite my comments and answer, I am voting to close this. Because none of us here work for WhatsApp and even if we did, why just share this here? Additionally, your question seems a bit like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) situation. If you have a more direct and focused question, feel free to post it. Otherwise, this question is not appropriate here.

Comment: @JakeGould However Signal's code is and the developers have published papers on both, Signal and WhatsApp about these topics.

Answer (score 2):

The Signal Sesame Algorithm (used by WhatsApp) specifies that messages are sent with end-to-end encryption between devices.

When someone sends you a message, it will be decrypted by your “main” device. This device will then re-encrypt the message and send it to your other devices (always with end-to-end encryption).

Each devices has its own key pair, and private keys are stored only on the device itself.

Source: “[The Sesame Algorithm: Session Management for Asynchronous Message Encryption](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/sesame/)”

Answer (score 1):

## Your assumption of what “end-to-end” encryption is is itself wrong.

### The encryption on WhatsApp is account-based “end-to-end” encryption; it is not a per-device form of encryption.

You state this and make a fairly broad assumption; bold emphasis is mine:

> “But because WhatsApp uses end-to-end encryption, **I should not be able to see messages sent from mobile on the web client, because it should use different pair of private/public keys.**”

The encryption on WhatsApp is account-based “end-to-end” encryption; it is *not a per-device form of encryption*. Meaning wherever you are logged in, your keys — existing or newly generated; I do not know how the intervals of WhatsApp are specifically — are used to manage your access to your account and messages. If your theory of how it works were true then — for example — if you most your phone, then how could you ever login to WhatsApp again? Read more on [their official FAQ](https://faq.whatsapp.com/general/28030015/):

> “WhatsApp end-to-end encryption ensures only you and the person you're communicating with can read what's sent, and nobody in between, not even WhatsApp.”

This all comes down to one thing: Your account only encrypts messages to — and from — your account. When you login to your account from a new device, the app — via whatever key management scheme WhatsApp uses — then connects that device to your WhatsApp account.

Comment: The encryption is actually device-based end-to-end. The devices of a single user use different key pairs, but messages are forwarded by the phone to the web client. If Alice and Bob are chatting, the communication is indeed not end-to-end between Alice and Bob's web client, but it's end-to-end between devices, each one using it's own key pairs.

Comment: When you log in with a new device (loose your phone, ..), Whatsapp authorizes this phone to register with your userID (linked to your phone number) by sending a text message to your phone number. But messages sent to you before the new phone registration are encrypted using your old phone public key, thus the new phone can't decrypt them.
Notice that when you setup whatsapp on a new phone (by downloading the app, not by using some iPhone/Android restoration tool to setup your new phone), you can't see your conversation history. And your contacts get a message saying your security code changed